# Excel Filter Formula based on another cell get any if empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I'm trying to get this sorted out for a while but can't seem to figure it out.

I am using the FILTER formula in order to filter a set of records in a table based on the value of a cell (actually multiple conditions, but nos really the point). The thing is, I would like the formula to filter the records if the condition cell has some text, but if it is empty, I would like it to return ALL records as if there was no filter, and I can't get it right...

This is the formula I am using:

```
=FILTER(Table;SI(D2<>"";Table[Streaming]=D2;Table[Streaming]=""))
```

Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you nest the `FIlTER()` inside an if?

Comment: Well actually that's when the multiple conditions get in the way. Since I am going to have around 8 conditions, that will make me have to use 8 nested ifs, since I want all of them with this behavior, so that won't work :(

Comment: Of course it would work. All critera can go on a Boolean statement in the 2nd parameter. Do you mind adding sample data, expected behaviour and output?

Comment: Well actually the formula would be extremelly complicated because since any of the filters can or cannot be blank, it would be a total mess... 
I think the ideal thing would be for this: Table[Streaming]=""   to be comparing to anything instead of "", but i just dont know how...

Comment: Put some sample data together and we can have a look.

Comment: See my answer. You can combine conditions with `*` for `AND` and with `+` for `OR`, and you can nest IF into the Filter conditions that way.

Answer (score 1):

Nesting formulas is powerful, when the syntax of the formula is well understood.
In the screenshot, this formula filters the table:

```
=FILTER(Table1,(IF(H2="",TRUE,Table1[Color]=H2))*(IF(H3="",TRUE,Table1[size]=H3))*(IF(H4="",TRUE,Table1[length]=H4)))
```

[image]

[image]

In case you want to duplicate the whole table if there are no filters specified, then wrap the above formula into an IfErrror() like this:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(Table1,IF(H2="",TRUE,Table1[Color]=H2)*IF(H3="",TRUE,Table1[size]=H3)*IF(H4="",TRUE,Table1[length]=H4)*(COUNTA(H2:H4)>1)),Table1)
```

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.